# My VSCode autocompletion extension does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I recently developed a CSS framework, and I developed a VSCode extension to help people in case they use my framework. When I finished the code and typed `vsce package` in the command to install the .vsix file, I pressed F5 and tried to use it. However, nothing happened. Could anyone please help me?

this my extension.ts file content

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

const classNames: string[] = [
    'container',
    'row',
    'col-md-12',
    'bg-primary',
    // add more class names as needed
];

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const provider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
        { language: 'html' },
        {
            provideCompletionItems
        },
        '.' // trigger on any character
    );

    context.subscriptions.push(provider);

    const addAutoCompleteWordCommand = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.addAutoCompleteWord', () => {
        vscode.window.showInputBox({
            prompt: 'Enter a new auto-complete word for HTML classes'
        }).then(newWord => {
            if (newWord) {
                // add the new word to the auto-complete words array
                classNames.push(newWord);
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`Added ${newWord} to auto-complete words`);
            }
        });
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(addAutoCompleteWordCommand);
}

function provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position) {
    // get the current line of code up to the cursor position
    const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.substr(0, position.character);

    // check if the current line contains a class attribute
    const classMatch = linePrefix.match(/class=["'](\w*\s*)*$/);
    if (classMatch && (document.languageId === 'html' || document.languageId === 'typescriptreact' || document.languageId === 'javascriptreact')) {
        // extract the class names from the class attribute
        const classNamesUsed = classMatch[0].split(/[ ="]/).filter(className => className.trim().length > 0);

        // filter the auto-complete words based on the class names already used in the attribute
        const filteredClassNames = classNames.filter(className => !classNamesUsed.includes(className));

        // map the filtered class names to vscode CompletionItem objects
        const completionItems = filteredClassNames.map(className => new vscode.CompletionItem(className, vscode.CompletionItemKind.Property));

        // return the completion items
        return completionItems;
    }
}
```

and this package.json file content

```json
{
  "name": "FHF",
  "displayName": "fhf",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.77.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [],
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "extension.addAutoCompleteWord",
            "title": "Add Auto-Complete Word"
        }
    ],
    "languages": [
        {
            "id": "html",
            "aliases": [
                "HTML"
            ],
            "extensions": [
                ".html"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "typescriptreact",
            "aliases": [
                "TypeScript React"
            ],
            "extensions": [
                ".tsx"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "javascriptreact",
            "aliases": [
                "JavaScript React"
            ],
            "extensions": [
                ".jsx"
            ]
        }
    ]

  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.77.0",
    "@types/glob": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "16.x",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.53.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.53.0",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "glob": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the reason for the `contributes.languages`

Comment: In the code, the contributes.languages section declares support for three languages: HTML, TypeScript React, and JavaScript React. This means that your extension will only provide autocompletion suggestions for these three languages, and not for any other language.

Comment: the first parameter to `registerCompletionItemProvider` determines for which language you auto complete, the `contribute` is to link extensions to languageIDs

Comment: Thank but I don't know why dos it work can you please provide me withe right one

Comment: you don't need to package if you use `F5` to test/debug the extension, create a launch config for extensions, package only if you want to send somebody the extension to install it by command line or via activity bar menu

Comment: Thank but still do not work